# Python2 to Python3 [Small Import Issue]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, compatibility, urllib

My code is no longer working after moving from **Python 2.7.9 to Python 3.4.3**. I am trying to get my little program to run on my RPI and when I tried running with 2.7.9 via `python server.py` I get this error:

**Code Issue:**

```
def setVolume(volume):
    volume = max(90, min(30, volume)) #Max Volume Spam Protection
    sendPost(speakerAddress+"volume","<volume>"+str(volume)+"</volume>")
```

Comment: You said "I get this error:", yet you've provided us with your code instead of an error? What's the actual **error**??

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `Request` object and yet you are trying to

```
return request.urlopen(address).read()
```

As far as I know you can keep your old `from urllib import request` in the new code aswell. Here's  what Python 3.4.3 docs say about it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

So you should be able to import `request` and `parse` from `urllib` in Python 3.4.3. If that doesn't work for you maybe consider reinstalling your Python 3.4.3 distribution.

Comment: So what is the fix for this then for I am confused honestly. TY for commenting :D For I can not run the script via `python2`

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, the code will work in `python3` but not in `python2`. So when I am running in `Python3` when I send a request for volume set of 50% it will always be received as 100% even when I try 30% or 20% and etc.

Comment: `python3` docs is quite clear about it. Try calling your raw `python3` interpreter in command line then try `from urllib import request, parse`. `urllib` is Python's kind of default lib and you should have it with your distribution. If you don't consider reinstalling maybe

Comment: I am running with `python3` interpreter with that code `from urllib import request, parse` but again my commands are not taken correctly when I text my RPI.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Like printing the whole request data?

Comment: Yes I have and even ran it on Windows and it works perfectly all commands are received perfectly no issues. SO I said why not run it on my RPI2. My windows `Python` is also the same version of 3.4.3.

Comment: So you're telling me you are sending a request with something like `{vol: 0.2}`, yet when you receive it the value is `{vol: 1.0}`? You need to say something more about the code

Comment: I figured it out! It was an issue with my volume handler. 
I had to comment out the volume = line but what is wrong with it? Please see my original question.